# How to express 'to some degree' and 'excessively' meaning exactly using 'rather'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

How can I know that the word **"rather"** is meaning  **to some degree** or **excessively** in a sentence?

They seem make sense to understand as any one of those two meanings in some examples below.

eg:

> It's rather(meaning **to some degree** or **excessively** ?) expensive.
>
> I rather(meaning **to some degree** or **excessively** ?)  think he was telling the truth.

And how to use **rather** when I want to express exactly **"to some degree"** or **"excessively"** in a sentence?

In one dictionary:

[image: Definition of 'rather']

and another dictionary:

[image: Definition of 'rather']

Comment: *Rather* does not mean *excessively*.  *Rather* can be used as an understatement to express that something is excessive, e.g. "it's rather expensive". But you could just as well say "it's somewhat expensive" to express the same meaning (i.e. "I cannot afford it").

Comment: The two meanings depend on whether you're using *rather* as a verb or adverb. In *I rather think* it's a verb.

Comment: That dictionary seems off to me. “He’s rather young to marry” doesn’t mean the same thing as 他年纪太小，还不能结婚 does. The Chinese sentence means “He’s too young to marry” (or more literally, “He’s too young; he can’t marry yet”). A translation that gets closer to the English meaning—though it feels less idiomatic—would be something like 他年纪对于结婚满小／有点儿小.

Comment: Cross-post of https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/119176/4376

Answer (score 2):

You have it all correctly except the second form:

I *rather think* he was telling the truth does not mean your thinking was excessive.  When you rather think, you are saying you **prefer to think** it. Instead of thinking he was lying to you, you rather think (prefer to understand) he was telling you the truth.

[Rather can mean *Prefer*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rather)

Comment: That would require an additional 'would'. "I rather think ..." (BrE) is quite different from "I'd rather think ...".

Answer (score 0):

When **rather** meaing degree , it similar to *quite* and *fairly* and *somewhat*.

"He was **rather** big" can mean anything from "***not small***" to "***huge***" .

---

Find that in [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rather)

Answer (score 0):

The word rather may not have the meaning "excessively" or "to some degree" always in English Language .

example 1 :- In that case I would rather refrain myself from going there but would send someone.

(Here it means a choice depending on situation or the Person decides)

example 2 : - He rather seems to be weak than strong during his teenage . 
              He rather seems to be strong than weak compared to his childhood.

(When you are not sure about someone and you get a surprise of someone's efforts or strength. Here to some degree or excessively can be used depending on less or more outcome )